# Want to mimic iphone address book search (In terms of interface & interaction)

Tags: iphone, search, uitableview

When you do a search in the address book the flow is:

1) Select the search bar

2) The right most transparent a-z index is removed

3) A transparent black window is placed over the current UITableView

4) When you begin typing, a new UITableView is loaded with no data

5) The UITableView is populated with data as you type.

6) If you select an item you are brought to it

7) If you cancel the search you return to the main UITalbeView

My first real question is, how do I load a new UITableView when a user begins searching? Is it as easy as popping a new view on the stack? It would then be a seperate .m/.h file with its own implementation?

The second question is how do you remove the right most index? Or just that just go away when you render the new (blank) UITableView?

I've gotten search working, but mine does it in the same UITableView, which when you start contains like 2K results, is grouped (A results under A Heading, etc) and has a right most index.

I'd be happy leaving the results in the table, if I could;

1) Remove the rightmost a-z index

2) Drop the table groupings

3) Tell the view I only have N search results so it will build the scroll bar correctly.

Thanks for your input;

- sk

Answer (score 0):

Use the new iPhone SDK 3.0 where this is provided for free by a new controller.

I can't say more because the iPhone SDK 3.0 is still under NDA.

Comment: Oh cool - Yeah I was going to test against is this weekend as per the requirement. I found out a similiar way to do this, minus the transparent black background.